# implement a static method of a class

Tags: c++11, static-methods

I have a header:

```
class a
{
 public:
  a();
  static int Zero();
  void SimpleEx();
}
```

and its cpp file:

```
a() { }
static int a::Zero() {return 0;}
void SimpleEx() { cout << a::Zero(); }
```

I get the error when compiling:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class a __cdecl a::Zero(void)" (?Zero@a@@SA?AV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: class a __thiscall a::SimpleEx(void)" (?SimpleEx@a@@QAE?AV1@XZ)

How to solve this?

Comment: try not using the static keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take "static" out of the definition:

Declaration:

```
class a
{
    static int Zero();
}
```

Definition:

```
int a::Zero()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem. But why can't I use static?

Comment: It's enough to declare the function as static.  The same reason you don't need to specify the access type in the definition again - you say it's "public" in the header, for example, it's enough.